# In Electron, why can't i assign values from node modules to angularjs views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, electron

I'm diving into Electron. I'm seeing some odd behavior:

**Question:**
Why is my object on the $scope not updating when i set data from a node module from within an angularjs controller?

**Context:** 
I'm using the node module adb-kit to detect an external android device.
I'm using AngularJS 1.5.X to render my views
I'm using ui-router to set the scope around my view

**Goal:**
Display data from the android device inside an angularJS view

**Code:**

```
app.controller('DetectionController', function($scope, $state) {
  console.log('DetectionController');

  //node modules
  var adb = require('adbkit');
  var client = adb.createClient();

  //AngularJS Render Scope
  $scope.model = {
    id: 11111,
    attached: true
  }

  var forceUpdate = function(id) {
    console.log('call', id);
    console.log('id type is: ', typeof id)
    $scope.model.id = id;
  }

  forceUpdate(22222);
  client.trackDevices()
    .then(function(tracker) {
      tracker.on('add', function(device) {
        forceUpdate(device.id); //this doesn't assign 
        console.log('Device %s was plugged in', device.id); //shows in console
      });
      tracker.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Tracking stopped');
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error('Something went wrong:', err.stack);
    });
});
```

**Console Output:**

```
DetectionController
detct.js:15 call 22222
detct.js:16 id type is:  number
detct.js:15 call 0168376B1701F01C
detct.js:16 id type is:  string
detct.js:26 Device 0168376B1701F01C was plugged in
```

**Expected Result:**
The final call to forceUpdate() should assign a value of 0168376B1701F01C and update the view

**Actual Result:**
The previous assignment of 22222 is still reflected in the DOM

**Ask:** How do i correctly assign a value from the node module and get the browser to update?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suspect the problem is with digest cycle not getting fired. Angular will trigger the digest cycle only during events recognized by angular. If you have custom event, then it is developers responsibility to let angular know to trigger digest cycle. Try changing the code to the following

```
client.trackDevices()
.then(function(tracker) {
  tracker.on('add', function(device) {
    forceUpdate(device.id); //this doesn't assign 
    console.log('Device %s was plugged in', device.id); //shows in console
    $scope.$apply();
  });
  tracker.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Tracking stopped');
  });
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.error('Something went wrong:', err.stack);
});
```

Comment: $scope.apply() resulted in a digest cycle error - using the same approach with $timeout() yielded the proper results.

Comment: @JackMurphy what digest cycle error did it throw btw?